# angular2 bind model value to radio button

Tags: angular

I have a model which takes boolean value: `rational_thinker: boolean;` I set it's value from my frontend through radio boxes as following:

```
<label #radio class="my-radio-label mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect">
<input #btn1 type="radio" value='true' [(ngModel)]='rational_thinker' name="rational_thinker" class="mdl-radio__button" (click)="getRationalThinker(btn1.value)">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">True</span>
</label>

<label #radio class="my-radio-label mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect">
<input #btn2 type="radio" value='false' [(ngModel)]='rational_thinker' name="rational_thinker" class="mdl-radio__button" (click)="getRationalThinker(btn2.value)">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">False</span>
</label>
```

and method that sets the value:

```
getRationalThinker(value){
    this.rational_thinker=value;
}
```

After initial save the value is stored to my backend, and when I retrieve it again I want the corresponding radio button to be pre-selected, right now it appears blank.

How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: You are then managing to get the correct value with `getRationalThinker()`, send it to BE and when exactly are you having trouble initiating the radios buttons? Does the page reload? Do you go from one page to another? Is it an asyncronus call?

Comment: I get an object from my backend in ngOnInit which has rational_thinker=true  (and couple of such similar boolean values) on any successive page load, all other fields are prepopulated but not radio buttons. I am updating my question with screenshot of what I am trying to say..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe is a type issue:

```
value='true' [(ngModel)]='rational_thinker'
```

Here, the `'true'` from the `value` is string type, while the `true` from your model is `boolean` type.

You could maybe solve this by:

**In Component:**

```
public rationalThinkerModel: boolean = true;
```

**In Template:**

```
<input #btn1 type="radio" value='rationalThinkerModel' [(ngModel)]='rational_thinker' name="rational_thinker" class="mdl-radio__button" (click)="getRationalThinker(btn1.value)">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">True</span>
</label>

<input #btn2 type="radio" value='!rationalThinkerModel' [(ngModel)]='rational_thinker' name="rational_thinker" class="mdl-radio__button" (click)="getRationalThinker(btn2.value)">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">False</span>
</label>
```

**Update:**

Try adding this instead:

```
[checked]="(rational_thinker === true) ? 'true' : 'false'"
```

Comment: No it did not help :(

Comment: @Nitish Check my update and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @Nitish You sure you have `FormsModule` correctly included?

Comment: [checked]="(rational_thinker === true) ? 'true' : 'false'" this worked. I was trying [checked]="rational_thinker === true"

Comment: Finally we managed to make it work! I'm glad! Also @CitizenNito deserves props! ;)

Comment: However, radio box populates but to false although the value returned is true. Let me investigate it

Comment: @Nitish If you are encountering issues you could try creating a function that returns boolean and just do: `[checked]="isSelected(rational_thinker)"`

Answer (score 4):

Use `[value]='true'` and `[value]='false'`.

If you use the vanilla `value='true'` the contents of the property are not interpreted by angular but taken to be a string. This way, you have a string "true" which is not strictly equal to the boolean true (which I assume your model has from the server).

Using `[value]` instead makes angular interpret the contents as *code*, so if the contents are *true* or *false*, they will be taken as booleans and match with your model (hence become pre-selected correctly).

*Edit: switched [ngValue] with [value] as [ngValue] seems to only work with select elements...*

Comment: for [ngValue]='true' it is giving me Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input' error

Comment: Try [value]='true' - I thought these were equivalent but maybe ngValue has been deprecated or something (I use it in working production code, though).

Comment: I tried that as well, but didn't help. I even tried [checked]="rational_thinker === true" but no help

Comment: I will give my +1 because our solutions should work! xD

Comment: I am trying exactly same, but I am facing the same issue. Can it be related to DOM update?

Comment: Well as the plnkr shows, the solution with [value]="true" should work. You must have some small type issue or another nuance going wrong - time to do some model inspection and console.log()ging ;)

Also, i recommend you use the ReactiveFormsModule and use the FormBuilder service for such an involved form. It will save you a lot of hassle once you get the hang of it, and leave you with a better seperation of concerns (less code in HTML). I recommend this video for a short intro to the difference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYv9lsrV0s4